# Behavior of 'return' and 'new' in constructors

Tags: javascript, object

I wonder what's the difference between these two calls:

```
var a = Array(1,2,3);
var b = new Array(1,2,3);
```

I tried to mimic the behavior this way:

```
function test() {
  return {x:42};
}

var a = test();
var b = new test();
console.log(a,b); // the same
```

How is that possible that `b` is the same like `a`? If `new` is used, the return value should be ignored:

```
function test() {
  return 1;
}

var a = test();
var b = new test();
console.log(a,b); // 1 test{}
```

Comment: `Array` probably internally does a check similar to this one: http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/21/basic-javascript-part-4-enforcing-new-on-constructor-functions/. If it's called with `new`, it will initialise its own contents with the passed arguments. If it's called as a plain function, it creates a new array for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call a function using `new`, a new object is created and passed into the function as `this`. If the function doesn't return anything (or returns a primitive), that new object that was passed in is the result of the `new` expression. **But**, if the function returns an object, that new object that was created is thrown away and the object returned by the function is the result of the `new` expression instead. This is covered in turgid prose in [Section 11.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) of the spec. It's mostly useful for immutable objects where the constructor maintains some kind of cache and reuses instances if the arguments are identical (or of course, singletons).

So in your example, since your `test` function returns an object, calling it via `new` just creates and throws away the object created by the `new` operator, and the result is the object you're returning from `test` instead.

I probably shouldn't say that the object from `new` is necessarily "thrown away" if you return a different object. The constructor might do something with the object from `new` that keeps it from being thrown away. For instance, you could write a constructor like this:

```
function WeirdConstructor() {
    return {
        theNewObject: this
    };
}
```

...which takes the object created by `new` and makes it a property of the object it returns. To call this a *special* scenario is to put it mildly. :-)

The fact that `Array(1, 2, 3)` and `new Array(1, 2, 3)` both return a new array is actually just a special feature of the `Array` constructor, covered by [Section 15.4.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1). The spec carefully lays out what each of the standard constructors does if you don't call them via `new`. The behavior varies. Many of them do type coercion, a couple like `Array` just act like you used `new` even though you didn't, and `Date` does a really weird thing (gives you a string version of the current date, basically `String(new Date())`).

---

Specifically regarding `Array`: I wouldn't use either `Array(1, 2, 3)` *or* `new Array(1, 2, 3)`. I'd use `[1, 2, 3]`. It's not ambiguous (does `new Array(3)` create a blank array with `length = 3` or an array with one entry, `3`, in it? what about `new Array("3")`?), and it's possible (though unlikely) someone could shadow the symbol `Array`, but they can't shadow the literal form. But I don't think that was the point of your question. :-)

Comment: Blow me away! Is this standard documented bahavior?

Comment: @JanTuroň: Yup, Section 11.2.2.